# Find duplicate settings in dotfiles

Tags: duplicate, dotfiles

I have copied some dotfiles settings, mostly from github, into my own dotfiles. Now I have the problem that some settings are duplicated and have same or different values. E.g. in Xresources:

```
xscreensaver.splash: false
```

and further below:

```
xscreensaver.splash: true
```

or

```
xscreensaver.Dialog.Button.foreground:  #EDEDFF
```

and further below:

```
xscreensaver.Dialog.Button.foreground:  #EDEDFF
```

Is there any way to find such settings automatically, preferably with a text editor, instead of doing it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the basic tools `cat <file> | cut -d ':' -f1 | sort | uniq -d` to see which settings you are talking about. Then just use your favorite editor...